# Put the read file in directory

Tags: python, string, file-io, directory

So I'm writing a function to open a file, read it and put it's content in a dictionary.

Basically the file that I'm reading looks like this:

```
Bread 10
Butter 6
Cheese 9
Candy 11
Soda 5
```

I want to make sure my dictionary will have this kind of form:

```
{ 'bread': 10, 'butter': 6, 'cheese': 9, 'candy': 11, 'soda': 5 }
```

So, how can I make sure the words will stay strings and I'll get out numbers as `int`?

So far this is how I can open my file but have no ideas how to go on.

```
def preberi_inventar(dn0501):
    f = open("dn0501.txt", "r")
    line = f.readlines()
    f.close()
```

Comment: first step is to starting doing something with that `line`... perhaps you could `split` it ?

Comment: I already got the answer, thank you anyway :)

Comment: ups, didn't see those :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = {}
with open("dn0501.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
       key, val = line.split()
       d[key] = int(val)
```

Comment: To get a number as requested you should use `d[key] = int(val)`.

Comment: @Matthias My bad. Thanks. Corrected the post.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be like this:

```
def preberi_inventar(dn0501):
    with open("dn0501.txt", "r") as f:
        return dict([row.split() for row in f])
```